# Could not update Application informations

Tags: facebook, submit, oauth-2.0

```
I submitted my app for app center several weeks ago and i got denied. But now i can't modify my auth dialog permissions without resubmitting.
```

I just wanna add the publish_actions permission without trying to submit again.

But in my other apps i can do it since i did not submit it.

What can i do?

Best

Answer (score 1):

The app center have to know which permissions you use in order to approve your app.

If you want to update premissions just click on "cancel subbmision" button, on app center and than you will have the ability to edit premission. (**If you don't see this button just try to resubmit it and than cancel**)

Hope it helped you :)